# C# приведение элементов к типу интерфейса IEnumerable

Tags: c#, типы-данных, интерфейс, ienumerable

В методичке идёт пояснение по поводу стандартных интерфейсов и ключевого слова yield:

Следующий пример демонстрирует перебор значений в заданном
диапазоне (от 1 до N) (пример 3.3).
Листинг 3.3 Статический метод реализующий интерфейс IEnumerable

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace StdIFace
{
    class ExampleIEnumerableClass
    {
        public static IEnumerable Count(int to)
        {
            int from = 1;
            while (from <= to)
                yield return from++;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (int i in Count(5))
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Из метода Count() возвращаются цифры от 1 до 5 включительно, при этом в самом методе эти цифры типа "int", а из метода эти цифры возвращаются уже с типом "IEnumerable". 
Далее в цикле foreach эти цифры присваиваются переменной "i" и при присвоении, получается, они явно преобразовываются из "IEnumerable" в "int" и потом уже выводятся в консольку(это так, как я понял).

Если я не правильно рассуждаю, поправьте, пожалуйста.

**Собственно вопрос:**

1. Получается типом "IEnumerable" может быть любой элемент?
2. Зачем из метода Count() возвращать цифры типа "IEnumerable", если можно их возвращать в их изначальном типе "int"?
   Да, это, насколько я знаю, нужно чтобы метод мог использоваться в цикле foreach, но почему foreach не переваривает типы отличные от "IEnumerable"?

Answer (score 6):

1) Нет. Типом `IEnumerable` может быть только тип, реализующий `IEnumerable`

2) Вы неверно поняли, что происходит. Вы видите по сути один код, но выполняется другой. При использовании ключевого слова `yield`, компилятор сгенерирует новый класс, реализующий IEnumerable, энумератор которого будет использовать вашу функцию для получения следующего элемента при перечислении. Подробнее [тут](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) - в секции `Returning IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, что тут происходит.

`IEnumerable` — это *последовательность элементов*. То есть, она представляет собой не один элемент, а несколько. Поэтому поменять возвращаемый тип метода `Count` на `int` не получится: с `int` вы можете вернуть лишь *одно* значение, а с `IEnumerable` — много.

Как ни странно, ваша методичка упоминает давно устаревший нетипизированный `IEnumerable`, в котором и правда в последовательности могут быть элементы *любого типа*. Более современный и эффективный вариант — `IEnumerable<int>`, который позволяет возвращать последовательность только `int`-значений.

`foreach` нужен для итерации по последовательностям, поэтому он не принимает одиночные элементы. Если бы функция возвращала просто `int`, вам не был бы нужен цикл.

---

Функция с `yield return` — это нестандартный, но очень популярный способ создавать последовательности. При этом оператор `yield return` не возвращает *результат* функции, а всего лишь одно, *следующее* значение элемента коллекции. В течение выполнения функции `yield return` может выполняться несколько раз (в отличие от `return`, который всегда выполняется лишь один раз), и каждый раз это даёт новое значение в последовательности.

---

Когда в цикле `foreach` происходит итерация по нетипизированному `IEnumerable`, и в коде задаётся тип переменной итерации (в вашем случае `int i`), происходит приведение типа элемента последовательности к типу `int`. (Если в вашей коллекции вдруг окажется не `int`, произойдёт ошибка приведения типов: https://ideone.com/epx61b.)

Comment: Мне показалось, что автор вопроса увидел это `yield return from++;` и решил, что тут идет приведение `int` к `IEnumerable`, что в корне неверно. То есть про `IEnumerable<int>` речи вообще не идет.

Comment: @tym32167: Может и так. Мне показалось, что он не знает вообще, что означает `yield return`, и думает, что функция возвращает `int`. Посмотрим, что скажет ТС.

Comment: @VladD, то, что означает `yield return` я знаю. Просто в foreach у нас тип `int` у переменной `i` и в переменную `i` возвращается значение из метода `Count()`. Значит, как я понял, идёт не явное приведение.

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади: Дополнил ответ.